# display an image above the content using absolute positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am just wondering how to display an image above the `<p/>` using absolute positioning. Note: the image has no define height, it could be longer or shorter. The goal is to  display the image above the  using absolute positioning.

```
<div id="wrap">
    <p>Hello</p>
</div>

<script>
    //Display an image above the <p/> using absolute positioning.
        //Note: the image has no define height, it could be longer or shorter. The goal is to 
         display the image above the <p/> using absolute positioning.
</script>
```

Comment: above the `<p/>`....what is <p/>...where do you want the image again....after `<p>` or after `</p>`???

Answer (score 1):

If you want an `<img>` above the `<p>`, is there a reason why you can't do the following?

```
<div id="wrap">
    <img src="path/to/img">
    <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

I would highly recommend this approach as the height or width of the image will not break anything and the `<p>` will move according to it's size.

But let's assume the `<img>` is elsewhere, like below it:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <p>Hello</p>
    <img src="path/to/img">
</div>
```

You can add the following CSS:

```
img {
    position: relative:
    top: -25px;
}
```

This is not a very good thing to do, though - as it literally just moves the image up 25 pixels. What if the size of the paragraph `<p>` changes? What if you add more content above the paragraph `<p>`?

You can also try:

```
img {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

This will put the image at the top of the viewport at all time. Again, using either of the these `position` methods present a lot of problems (unless it's what you want) and I recommend my first suggestion using pure HTML, and avoiding CSS position fixes.

Answer (score 0):

I see no smart way to do this... why not $("#wrap").before("image"); without absolute position?

Comment: That's the thing, I need it to be in absolute position

Answer (score 0):

If you mean in terms of hiding, there you go:

**Markup**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>I will be hidden soon.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper img{
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.wrapper').append($('<img>', { src : 'http://placehold.it/350x150'}));
```

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2FJmK/)